# How can I add an external Haskell package to a stack project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I would like to add [`req`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-1.0.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html) to my Stack project. I can install this on my machine with `stack install req` but I would like to list this in the project dependencies so it is downloaded when the project is built if it is currently not installed.

`stack.yaml` looks like the place to do this but I couldn't find any info on how it's done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `stack.yaml` file, under the `extra-deps` section, add your dependency. Example:

```
extra-deps:
- req-1.0.0
```

Note that you specify the version in the `extra-deps` if that's not in that particular stackage resolver (the resolver is specified in the `stack.yaml` file in the field `resolver`). In case, it's present in the stackage resolver - all you have to do is specify that package name under `build-depends` section in your cabal file (or the package.yaml file if you are using `hpack`).

More documentaion is [available here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#extra-deps).

Comment: Ah I figured it would be there but it wasn't working. I was missing the version number as well.